# Swift app was working fine,now shows it goes white and minimizes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am developing an app with swift and xcode and i gave it to a tester.It was working fine for a while but after 3 days he came back and showed it to me.
When he lauches the app,it goes white and gets minimised immediately and.
Then after a week the same but now it took longer.

Note:
I used his phone as an emulator to load the app

Xcode 9.4.1
Swift 4.0
ios 11.4

Comment: Because of crash, you need to debug your app

Comment: Do you have a paid membership of the developer program?

Comment: @Paulw11 no i don't.i thought this might be the case and i am still waiting for a paid account.

Comment: Apps developed with a free membership need to be rebuilt every few days

Comment: It might be due to, as Paul said, an expired certificate since your account isn't a paid dev account. You need to rebuild the app and see it it works. It it doesn't, you are having a crash.

Answer (score 0):

It supposed to be crashed, connect the device to your MacBook and run the application through Xcode, it will show you the error.

Comment: Why it is supposed to?It only makes sense if you need a paid account i guess

Comment: Sorry I forgot this case, If you are using a free account then app would laster longer for a few days. You have to rebuild again.